# Как в Visual Studio исключить некоторые файлы из поиска?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-extensions

Как в Visual Studio 2015 при поиске текста по файлам (указана область поиска "Все решение") исключить из поиска некоторые файлы (например, минифицированные)?

Answer (score 0):

В Visual Studio есть несколько видов поиска.

При нажатии Ctrl+F (меню Edit > Find and Replace > Quick find) появляется простое окошко поиска.

При нажатии Ctrl+Shift+F (меню Edit > Find and Replace > Find in Files) появляется окно поиска с большим количеством настроек. В пункте Find Options можно указать типы файлов.

---

Добавлю для полноты картины.

В правом верхнем углу Студии есть окошко Quick Launch (Ctrl+Q) - можно быстро искать пункты меню.

В Solution Explorer есть собственный поиск по дереву пунктов  (Ctrl+;) - удобная фича, когда нужно что-то найти в огромном решении.

---

Пардон, не разглядел, что нужно **исключить** файлы. Стандартных средств нет.

В аналогичной [теме](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1596337/5045688) на en.so в ответах предлагают воспользоваться Power Shell или установить расширение для Студии.

Comment: PowerShell что-то выдает, но по клике на результаты файл с найденным текстом не открывается, как при обычном поиске по файлам.

Comment: Расширение возможно подошло бы, но я не найду ни одного для VS 2015. Тот, что указан в аналогичной теме (Ultra Find), видимо, уже не поддерживается.